Singe Page Application for the Web with (dynamic) tabbed interface - is there need for the navigation and url update for ERP application?
I am developing React SPA ERP application (so - no SEO requirement) with dynamic tabbed interface - where each form (e.g. invoice id=1, invoice id=2, invoice new, list of invoices, accounting report) opens in new in-application tab, like described https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65357960/code-design-for-the-multidocument-tabbed-interface-for-react-spa-with-react-rout
One can imagine that such tab management should be done by routing - all the navigation calls should be routed to the TabLayout component (lets call them it by this name) and this component listens to the incoming calls and manages tabs - e.g. maintains list of tabs and activeTabId, adds new tab, removes existing, switched).
But - is there is no SEO need and no need for the URL changes, then maybe all navigation calls can be just direct updates to the list of opened tabs and activeTab, avoiding any routing?
This is a bit design question - does not-SEO multi-tabbed SPA applications require to show the active tab in browser url and hence - does it require navigation mechanism? What is the custom approach in such setting? Can I loose anything by avoiding navigation and just having one URL for the entire SPA application (that can not be implemented by local storage or just processing of the initial url - e.g. if specific document url is entered)?
So - essence of my question is - is it bad (and against the best practices) to avoid navigation in the SPA application?

You're only thinking about how a user navigates around the app after they've entered it from the initial page. You're not thinking of any other use cases, one major one being:

Hey Bob, I was looking at your comments in PO 5542 and I was wondering if this is because their customer account is set to international only?
For comparison, FooBar is able to cancel their POs, and their customer account is set to local and international.

The ability to link to specific resource views in your app, so that people can communicate with direct references to what they're communicating about. Where do people get those URLs? They navigate to the resource, and then copy the URL.
If your application does not update its browser URL, then all of those links in the above message would all link to the main page of the application. That would be a horrible user experience.
Equally importantly, a lot of people tend to use bookmarks for frequently visited content, which similarly requires a URL in order to get direct access to that resource.
While you could technically build a bookmark system in your application to handle that, (a) it's more work (b) it needlessly forces people to use your way of doing things and shut out any better tooling they would otherwise be using and (c) it prevents people who use multiple applications from keeping their bookmarks in one location.
All of this is done on the implicit assumption that a URL is invariably tied to the view that the user is seeing, so that the URL can be shared/stored and later opened to get access to the same view.


So - essence of my question is - is it bad (and against the best practices) to avoid navigation in the SPA application?

There's nothing inherently wrong with adding extra navigation features in your application. However, that's not what your question is asserting. You're not asking if it's okay to have tabbed navigation in your app, you're asking if it's okay to break the conventional ways of navigation because you think it's not necessary.
Zooming out for a moment, you're very close to falling in the classic "I can do it better" developer trap. No you (probably) can't. Or, as XKCD put it:

I know how you got here. This is a step by step process.

I have an idea for navigation in my app.
I'm going to build it.
This actually supplants the conventional methods.
After the effort of building my own navigation method, I realize that making it compatible with the conventional method requires additional effort.
Well I guess we break the conventional method then - who needs it anyway when they've got access to my way of navigating?

It goes off the rails at step 5.
Taking away conventional methods and tooling will significantly frustrate your users. Your application will create additional friction for anyone who wants to start using it because it outright rejects integration into what are considered normal and conventional web standards.
So, let's address this at the root.

I am developing React SPA ERP application with dynamic tabbed interface

There are two considerations to make here.
1 - Should you build your own tabs? What makes you believe that your tabs are better than the tabs of the web browser that your users use to access your application?
If you can't come up with any meaningful improvement on the existing tooling, there's no point to building it (unless you're doing it purely as a training exercise, but then you wouldn't really need to put it in an actual app that actual people will be using).
2 - Should you disable conventional tabs? Is there a reason you specifically cannot allow conventional tabs to exist? Does it create an active problem/conflict? Or are you simply assuming that everyone will inherently favor your in-app navigation solution?
The overall idea I'm trying to get across here is that it takes many stars to align in order for me to okay the idea that you should just willfully break convention here. It would require you to (a) actually need your custom tab feature because it provides something that is essential, (b) have this create a conflict with conventional tabbing, (c) cannot possibly resolve this conflict and therefore cannot possibly allow both navigation methods to exist, and (d) your users are forced to use this application (e.g. by their employer) and therefore their opinion on losing access to conventional tabbing doesn't really affect the success of your application.
Or, you could just stop this entire exercise in trying to assert that your solution is superior, and just update the damn URL and be done with it.

For those who feel like I ended this answer abruptly and rudely, I want to explicitly point out that OP's basis for their question is attempting to cut a corner on the amount of effort required to build the app. What I'm trying to point out here is that trying to figure out if this is a corner that can reasonably be cut takes more effort than not cutting the corner in the first place; thus making it a moot exercise that achieves the opposite of what it intended to.
The abrupt ending of this answer highlights how simple it is to just update the URL in the browser, compared to the lengthy process of even just listing all the issues and ramifications of not doing so, let alone evaluating them on a cost/benefit/risk scale.
